# Inline function in a select sub query or create view

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I need some suggestion, how can I use an inline function in a select sub query or create view. My code is giving me following error.

I used this [link](http://db-oriented.com/2015/11/14/write-less-with-more-part-8/) and the last solution suggested is the exactly what I am also trying to do.

Code:

```
select  /*+ WITH_PLSQL */ calc from
(
with 
function calculator (m number, r number) return number
is begin
return m * r;
end calculator;
select calculator(3, 2) as calc from dual
);
```

Error:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || member submultiset
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement.

Comment: @user75ponic, point is I created this inline 'with function' and I want to select data from this function as shown in the code.. But I am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: I can reproduce this error in 12c. So, it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this issue on AskTOM, and you can see the whole discussion thread in the following link: [Solution for above issue](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9534452300346807610)

The problem was with the SQL developer, In SQLPlus this query works fine.